# Gaussian copula and independence

Tags: copula, multivariate-normal-distribution

It is well-known that Gaussian copula has parameterizations of a correlation matrix. 
Let us say there are $n$ continous marginal random variables equipped in a Gaussian copula with an identity matrix. Dose this copula structure implies that these random variables are independent?

Comment: What do you mean by 'a Gaussian copula with an identity matrix'?

Comment: There is a unique copula corresponding to independent variables and you know what it is from the very definitions of "copula" and "independent": its value at any point $\mathbf{X}\in[0,1]^n$ is given by the product of the components of $\mathbf X.$ Thus, all you have to do is compare the Gaussian copula for the identity correlation matrix to the independence copula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all off-diagonal elements of the correlation matrix are 0, then the Gaussian Copula takes the shape of the independence copula (i.e. the copula density is 1 in $[0,1]^n$). Hence, the random variables are independent.

Be aware, that *uncorrelated* does in general not go along with *independent*. The Student t-Copula, which is also parameterised by a correlation matrix, does only approximate the independence copula for a degree of freedom $\rightarrow \infty$ (see the plot below for the 2-dimensional case and a small degree of freedom). Note, that even the upper and lower tail dependence coefficients achieve a value of 0.3 while the correlation is 0.

[image]